# Border when line-height is smaller than font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element(for example `<p>` or `<h1>`) with `line-height` property smaller than `font-size` property.  This forces the text inside the element to stick outside of it. I cannot unfortunately change this because it would change the design of the page.

This would be fine by itself but I have to add a `border`(or an `outline`) around this element. Now just as expected, the border will wrap around the element, not the text, which creates something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2vrp91zh/).

Now I could just edit each border individually but that would be really exhausting since I have to implement this on a lot of places on the website.

Another solution that came to my mind is `display: inline`. This wraps the border directly around text, however it starts acting really weird on elements with multiple lines.

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1uz4t5Lx/1/).

**Are there any other ways to make the border the same height as the text? I am open to both css and js solutions.**

Answer (score -1):

You might try adding this to your CSS:
outline-offset: 15px;
you might need to choose a different number depending on your situation.

Comment: Yea, I mentioned that in the post. This is a way to do this but I was looking for something more universal because I have to do this in a lot of places.